# Is "the powers that be" a set phrase in "- the last an unsolicited testimonial from the powers that be"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, [Epilogue, passage 426](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Epilogue), published 1892)

(passage 426)

> The tone of the age, its movement, the mingling of races and classes in the dollar hunt, the fiery and not quite unromantic struggle for existence with its changing trades and scenery, and two types in particular, that of the American handy-man of business and that of the Yankee merchant sailor—we agreed to dwell upon at some length, and make the woof to our not very precious warp. Hence Dodd's father, and Pinkerton, and Nares, and the Dromedary picnics, and the railway work in New South Wales—**the last an unsolicited testimonial from the powers that be**, for the tale was half written before I saw Carthew's squad toil in the rainy cutting at South Clifton, or heard from the engineer of his “young swell.” After we had invented at some expense of time this method of approaching and fortifying our police novel, it occurred to us it had been invented previously by someone else, and was in fact—however painfully different the results may seem—the method of Charles Dickens in his later work.

My problem there is the wording "the powers that be". Is "the powers that be" a set phrase or is "that be" a set phrase, and in addition what does this wording mean in this context? I take the wording "the powers that be" to be a set phrase of a sort and to mean something like "the higher powers" or "the power of a storm" or "the forces of nature", right? Possibly, this parlance is obsolete.

Comment: The whole phrase 'the powers that be' is a set phrase, meaning 'the relevantly important people who have authority over others'. See [the entry for that phrase](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/powers-that-be) in the Cambridge Dictionary.

Comment: Please check dictionaries before you post. It is a phrase that is still **much used**.

Comment: To Lambie's point, you should explain why [the definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20powers%20that%20be) - "the people who decide what is allowed or acceptable in a group, organization, etc." - didn't help you.

Comment: Do you mean "important people who have authority over others" really communicates the meaning of "the powers that be" **in this context**? Doesn't the catastrophe in the cutting of South  Clifton bear testimony to a transpersonal power beyond human authority instead? (passage 339 et seqq.)    https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_22

Comment: @ all - Do you think "the people who decide what is allowed or acceptable in a group, organization, etc." really expresses the meaning of "the powers that be" **in this context**?  Doesn't the catastrophe in the cutting behind South Clifton bear testimony to a transpersonal power beyond human authority instead?https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_22 . . . (passage 339 et seqq.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is a set phrase. It means "the existing ruling authorities" (from Chambers). It is generally used to mean the establishment in general and not necessarily the actual government. Who it refers to specifically will depend on the context. And it's definitely not obsolete. It would be currently understood by a native speaker and wouldn't even sound particularly old-fashioned.